# monodevelop crashes with WebRequest

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, webrequest

This problem has kind of stumpped me for the last couple of hours. Any clue why the application is crashing with this callstack in monodevelop. It will compile and run correctly if I build the application with xbuild.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.WebRequest' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.Init (IConfigSystem system, System.String configPath, System.Configuration.Configuration parent) [0x00065] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:137 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x0005c] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:96 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x0003b] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:91 
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationFactory.Create (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) [0x0000e] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/InternalConfigurationFactory.cs:41 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationInternal (ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, System.Reflection.Assembly calling_assembly, System.String exePath) [0x00102] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:119 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x00011] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:49 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x00025] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:52 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ClientConfigurationSystem.cs:61 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:159 
  at System.Net.WebRequest..cctor () [0x00014] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebRequest.cs:71 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest (System.Uri address) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs:285 
  at ParkitectNexus.Data.Web.Client.NexusWebClient.GetWebRequest (System.Uri uri) [0x00003] in /home/michaelpollind/Desktop/ParkitectNexusClient/src/ParkitectNexus.Data/Web/Client/NexusWebClient.cs:70 
  at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsync (System.Uri address, System.Object userToken) [0x0003b] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs:1846 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at ParkitectNexus.Data.Web.API.ParkitectNexusAPI+<GetRequiredModIdentifiers>c__async1.MoveNext () [0x000b8] in /home/michaelpollind/Desktop/ParkitectNexusClient/src/ParkitectNexus.Data/Web/API/ParkitectNexusAPI.cs:86 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at ParkitectNexus.Client.Base.Pages.AssetsPageView+<GetRequiredMods>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0007c] in /home/michaelpollind/Desktop/ParkitectNexusClient/src/ParkitectNexus.Client.Base/Pages/AssetsPageView.cs:62 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__1 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1010 
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state) [0x0000e] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:1291 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00081] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:581 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:530 
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x0002a] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:1268 
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00096] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:859 
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:1196
```

Comment: what version of monodevelop is this?

Comment: I'm using version 5.9.6

Comment: it actually seems to be a mono problem, what version of mono do you have, and how did you install it? and what OS and version is this?

Comment: I'm on fedora and im using the mono-complete packages for centos; here is the specific package: mono-complete-4.2.3.4-0.xamarin.1.x86_64. This is the mono version with mono --version command. Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3 (Stable 4.2.3.4/832de4b Tue Mar 15 11:39:54 EDT 2016)

Comment: I've read somewhere that the fedora packages of mono are not very well maintained, if I were you I would test Ubuntu16.04 to see if it fixes your problem

Comment: i'm using an ubuntu system and i'm still getting exception.

seems to be happening here:  using (var stream = await webClient.OpenReadTaskAsync(_website.ResolveUrl("api/assets/required", "client")))

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found that creating a separate project and copying everything into it seems to have resolved the configuration error. If anyone has any insight into this, I would like to know.